# "Permutation matrix" but non-zero entries are replaced by $e^{ix}$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, convex-polytopes, permutations, simplicial-complexes

Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem states that a polytope formed by a set of doubly-stochastic matrices has extreme points that are permutation matrices.

I am wondering if there is a similar theorem for a permutation matrix whose elements are replaced by some values of $e^{ix}$.

Comment: Does "some values of $e^{-i\omega}$" mean "some norm-$1$ complex numbers"?

Comment: These matrices are called "complex permutation matrices". I don't know any result that describes their convex hull, but they are exactly the isometries of the $p$-norms ($p \neq 2$) on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Edited the title and text: changed $e^{-i\omega}$ to $e^{ix}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A statement similar to the Birkhoff theorem holds: these matrices are the extreme points of the set of matrices for which the $\ell_1$ norm of each row and column is $\leq 1$. I denote by $K$ this set.

It is clear that every such matrix is an extreme point in $K$. Conversely, let $A$ be an extreme point in $K$. The $\ell_1$ norm of each row and column must be $1$. Write the entrywise polar decomposition, i.e. write $A$ as an entrywise product $A=U \circ B$ where $B$ is a bistochastic matrix and $U$ a matrix with entries having modulus $1$. The matrix $B$ is an extremal bistochastic matrix: if $B=(B_1 + B_2)/2$ for bistochastic matrices $B_1 \neq B_2$, then the equation $A = (U \circ B_1+U\circ B_2)/2$ contradicts the extremality of $A$. By the usual Birkhoff theorem, $B$ is a permutation matrix and the result follows.